# jQuery: Using a Time Delay in an Each Iterator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a carousel effect that automatically cycles through each pictures every 3 seconds.

```
    $(".headline_img").each(function(intIndex){
        setTimeout($(this).show(),3000);
    });
```

The timeout delay is not working.

This shows all of the images instantly as soon as the dom loads. It's like its ignoring the setTimeout function.

Did I miss something?

Note: I'm calling this using $(document).ready, do you think that might effect it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setTimeout` function takes a function reference or a string. Your code calls the `show` method for each element immediately. I'm not sure if this will work:

```js
$(function () {
  var t = 3000, $debug = $('#result');
    $(".headline_img").each(function(){
      var $img = $(this);
        setTimeout($img.show.bind($img), t);
      t += 3000;
    });
});
```

```css
.headline_img { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="headline_img">One</div>
<div class="headline_img">Two</div>
<div class="headline_img">Three</div>
```

but it's worth a try...

Comment: Didn't even notice that Mike, good call. Hopefully @dMix can confirm if that's the problem. The timeout will still need to be staggered for each element rather than being fixed at 3000.

Comment: True. My eyes went right to the parens since I've been bitten by that particular problem many times. ;-)

Comment: `$.fn.show()` will lose what its `this` should be, right?

Comment: Whoa, blast from the past :). It won't lose track of `this`, because we're passing a reference to a function already bound to `$(this)`. I've updated the code to make that clearer, although the `bind()` isn't strictly necessary. Good question though!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the timeout for each one. Right now, you're attaching the same timeout to all of them at the same time. Something like this should work without changing your code much:

```
$(".headline_img").each(function(intIndex){
    setTimeout($(this).show(),3000 * (intIndex +1));
});
```

Refactoring to use [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) might be more robust in the long term.

Comment: thanks this helps for staging the shows in sequence. but it is still showing all of the images at once with no time delay.

Comment: Are the images hidden by default when the page loads and the jQuery doesn't run? Do you need to add a `$(this).hide();` before the `setTimeout`?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use jQuery's [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) function.

```
$(".headline_img").each(function(intIndex){
    $(this).delay(3 * (intIndex + 1)).show();
});
```